# anchor tag and name attribute animated scroll

Tags: jquery, menu

i have done this http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/WsxJy/3/ using with anchor tag and name attributes.

but i need to do using with jquery like below link.
http://www.jibevisuals.com/

when click on "about us" menu page moves slowly up. I need that kind of work.

Any suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know why this was voted to be closed? and especially for that silly reason, I would of thought this would have been a duplicate answer but I guess people just close questions for no reason these days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Description

You can do this using `jQuery.offset()` and `jQuery.animate()`.

Check out the [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/6/).

#### Sample

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

scrollToAnchor('id3');
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/6/)
- [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
- [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this -> http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#source-code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a').click(function() {
    if ($.attr(this, 'href').indexOf("#")!=-1&&$.attr(this, 'href')!="#")
    {
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
    });
```

So if you using the following link: 
`<a href="#home"></a>`

 and put anchors to the right place:
 
`<a id="home"></a>` 
it will scrolled to the anchor tag smoothly.

This free jQuery Menu Plugin works with this method: [PageScroll jQuery Menu Plugin](https://github.com/Pantherius/pagescroll-jquery-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

Snake Eyes answer is the most dynamic option since you don't have to code every tag in js. All the client has to do is use the HTML solution, better for CMS control.

This little code snippet is all you need (well, ofcourse jQuery too)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Even have a solution for a stickymenu on top of the page, notice to replace #main_menu with the id or class of your menu:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var height_menu = $("#main_menu").css("height");
            height_menu = parseInt(height_menu,10);

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - height_menu
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```